# Нестабильная работа Callback Api VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, flask, heroku

Всем привет. 
Есть сервис который принимает сообщения от VK, что-то с ними делает и отправляет 'ok'.
Сообщение от VK передаются с помощью `callback api`.
На текущий момент в группе настроил несколько событий, которые будут отправляться на мой сервис.

Все работало замечательно до вчерашнего (29.10.2019) вечера. Вчера VK в определенные моменты просто отказывался отправлять сообщения в мой сервис, я снимал логи - входящего трафика - 0. И самое что странное, чтобы реанимировать события, надо отправить новое сообщение в группу и не факт что все уйдет, а если уходит (срабатывает `callbac`k), то только последнее сообщение.

Вопрос, наверное, больше к разрабам VK - WTF? 
Ну и может кто знает как это победить) ну или хотя бы как-то минимизировать))

Comment: А Вы проверьте на вкладке по работе с `Callback API`, какие уведомления и когда Вам приходили. Там можно посмотреть и ответ Вашего сервера.

Comment: Да, забыл указать. Там эти события - которые до меня не дошли присутствуют. Но у меня подозрение что это какая-то бага в ВК. У меня нечего не приходило))) также я не нашел как посмотреть ответы на запросы. И кстати ошибочных запросов - нет)))

Comment: Действительно не работает. Только что проверил у себя.

Comment: [Отчёт](https://vk.com/bug175353) по багу уже есть. Осталось ждать фикса.

Comment: Печаль конечно) 
У меня кстати нет доступа к данной баге (